# Redirect the output of 'time' to a file

Tags: adb, shell

I'm getting the following error when trying to capture the output of time to a file ([reference](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/032)).

```
adb shell su 0 "{ time -p echo hello world; } 2> /data/local/tmp/file"
/system/bin/sh: syntax error: unexpected '}'
```

But the command is successful when running without su i.e. **adb shell "{ time -p echo hello world; } 2> /data/local/tmp/file"**

Please provide inputs on why it's not working when running with su.

Comment: Both ADB and Android's `su` aren't very sane when it comes to handling arguments. Quote the whole command you are passing to `adb shell`. Also provide `-c` to `su` like `adb shell 'su -c "{ time -p echo hello world; } 2> /data/local/tmp/file"'`.

Comment: ```-c``` with ```su``` is not working in my environment. It's throwing invalid uid/gid error. I checked with giving the command ```adb shell 'su 0 "{ time -p echo hello world; } 2> /data/local/tmp/file"'```, then it's considering entire thing as a command name. It's throwing the error ```su: failed to exec { time -p echo hello world; } 2> /data/local/tmp/file: No such file or directory```.

Comment: You must be correct. As I already said, behavior of `sh` and `su` on Android devices is very much inconsistent. Strange things occur, even on different Android versions, particularly related to arguments and I/O streams. Better not rely on it for scripting. For interactive use first do `adb shell` and then run the command.

Comment: I'm getting similar error when I tried  to run the same command with sudo ```sudo { time -p echo hello world; } 2> /tmp/file``` in ubuntu terminal, but the command is successful without sudo.

Comment: Obviously that won't work. `sudo` runs an executable (the first argument), optionally with some arguments. But `{` is not and executable. Also your command ends at `;`, so the terminal shell (bash or whatever you are using) doesn't know what `}` is. Because it's also not an executable, neither shell's built-in command. `{` and `}` just create a block within current shell to group some commands, like `(` and `)` create a sub-shell. So you need to run like: `sudo sh -c '{ time -p echo hello world; } 2> /tmp/file'`. I suggest you read about how to work with shell. It's not Android specific.